# C++ Tetris functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to start a project that makes the game, Tetris. For this part, I already have seven unique 2-dimensional arrays that will represent Tetriminos (Tetris pieces), and I need help to create two functions to rotate those 2-dimensional arrays: rotateLeft() and rotateRight(). It will rotate 90 degrees in the specified direction. E.g. RotateLeft() would move row 1 values to col 1; row 2 to row 2; etc. And to have a function called printTetrimino to print the contents of a 2-d tetrimino array to the console window. I am just having problems on how to finish the rotateRight function and to start on the rotateLeft function. And for this project, I would like to not use classes and vectors. Please let me know how to do this because I am struggling. I need the understand how it works. Thank you! Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// function implementations
void rotateRight();

int main() {

};

int tetromino[7][4][4][4] =
{
    // Square piece
    {
    {
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    },
    // I piece
    {
    {
    { 1,1,1,1 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,1,1 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    },
    },
    // L piece
    {
    {
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,1,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 0,0,1,0 },
    { 1,1,1,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    },
    // J piece
    {
    {
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,1,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,1,0 },
    { 0,0,1,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    },
    // S piece
    {
    {
    { 0,1,1,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 0,1,1,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    },
    // N piece
    {
    {
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,1,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,1,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    },
    // T piece
    {
    {
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 1,1,1,0 },
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    {
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,1,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    },
    },
};

void rotateRight() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        int temp = tetromino[i][0];
        tetromino[i][0] = tetromino[i][1];
        tetromino[i][1] = -temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what it is to "rotate" these.  Imagine the segments making the pieces were lego (or whatever), what's the procedure for rotation?  How does each piece move?  Use this "actual world" recipe to develop a plan, then convert this plan into pseudo-code, then into C++ code.  (And *then* maybe google "array rotation").

Comment: "_I would like to not use classes and vectors_" Why? A `Tetrimino` class with rotate functions would be the first thing I'd suggest creating.

Answer (score 0):

The first question you need to ask yourself is which 4x4 array do you want to rotate? You have 28 4x4 arrays, at the moment how is `rotateRight` going to know which one of those to rotate? The answer is to add some parameters to rotateRight

```
// piece is a value from 0 to 6, e.g. 0 for square piece, 1 for I piece etc
// orientation is 0 to 4, its the version of the piece to rotate
void rotateRight(int piece, int orientation) {
    ...
}
```

Next point, when you are trying to rotate a 2D 4x4 array it makes no sense to loop from 0 to 15. You need two loops each 0 to 3

```
// piece is a value from 0 to 6, e.g. 0 for square piece, 1 for I piece etc
// orientation is 0 to 4, its the version of the piece to rotate
void rotateRight(int piece, int orientation) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            tetromino[piece][orientation][i][j] = ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

That gives you a start, hopefully you can fill the rest in.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [rotating 2d arrays inplace is much more complicated than you first think. Please read the tutorial carefully before you proceed](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/). Now putting that tutorial together with your code seems to be almost perfect except you'll have to figure out how to do that clockwise yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 4

void rotateMatrix(int mat[][N]) { 
    // Consider all squares one by one 
    for (int x = 0; x < N / 2; x++) { 
        // Consider elements in group of 4 in  
        // current square 
        for (int y = x; y < N-x-1; y++) { 
            // and so on
        } 
    } 
} 

void main() {
    int tetromino[4][4]={
    { 0,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,1,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    };

    rotateMatrix(tetromino);

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<4; x++) {
            printf("%i", tetromino[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Then Again, did you notice that your array has a fourth dimension and contains all the rotations?